# How do I add synonyms in regexp.json?

Tags: watson-assistant-solutions

After I added the following synonyms in regexp.json, regexp engine has failed to start.
How is the rule of adding synonyms in regexp.json?

```
{
  "intents" : [
    {
      "name" : ["greetings"],
      "grammar" : [
      "morning"
  ]
}
 ],

  "entities" : {
  },

  "synonyms" : [
    "good-bye","hello"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

synonyms should be a list of arrays within an array.  Try this

"synonyms" : [ 
        [ "goodbye", "bye", "bye bye", "bye now","ok bye","then bye","bye then", "adieu", "adios", "au","ciao", "toodles" ],
        [ "hi", "hello", "aloha", "bonjour", "buenous", "greetings", "Hey", "heya", "Hola", "yello","yo"]
]

Does that work?